# Monitoring interface changes with udev, especially if a route is set

Tags: networking, monitoring, ip, udev

Is there a way to monitor interface up/downs, especially to check if a route is setup or removed, with udev?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am really not sure (and highly doubt it) if `udev` provides an interface for it but you can easily monitor it without `udev`. You just have to use a [netlink socket](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/netlink.7.html) with [NETLINK_ROUTE](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html) to get notifications about changed addresses, changed routing tables etc.